# Angular 6 - store global variables and data

Tags: angular6, global

I've wondered where is the best place to store shared data and global vars in Angular 6.
I know I can set them on a service that can be injected to any of my components, but I'm sure there's a better practice...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure it is the best practice, but if you want variable to be available in all places without any injections, you can use the global "window" object. it is not an angular way but if your project work with external libraries that didn't written in angular it can help you to communicate with it easily. 
for example, you can type window.x = "something" to create new variable in the window object.